# cany understand php oracle function oci_commit()

Tags: php, oracle

I read the following in the [PHP/Oracle manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-commit.php) from php.net:

> A transaction begins when the first SQL statement that changes data is executed with `oci_execute()` using the `OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT` flag. Further data changes made by other statements become part of the same transaction. Data changes made in a transaction are temporary until the transaction is committed or rolled back. Other users of the database will not see the changes until they are committed.

There are two things that I don't understand:

1. What is committing for?
2. What does that mean that "other users of the database will not see the changes until they are committed?" How will not they able to see the changes?

Comment: This should be good basic reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should read some more about transactions.

Simply put - you can think of any query within a transaction as a draft, a temporary data set, that only you(within your database session/connection) can see, unless you issue a commit.

Another analogical explanation is to think of transactions as your thoughts on something that you would actually write down on paper afterwards. The commit is the act of actually writing it so it no longer exists only in your head.

Answer (score 1):

Committing is the finalization of the transaction in which the changes are made permanent.

Because Oracle has the read consistent view, users that start a transaction will only be able to see data that was committed when the new transaction started. So when user A starts a transaction and user B changes some values in a table and commits it, user A won't see the changed data until user A starts a new transaction. The read consistent view makes sure that all users always see a consistent state, one with all data committed.

This causes that a single block of a table can have multiple versions in the undo tablespace, just to support the read consistent views for various transactions.

Comment: ahaaaaaaaaaaaa, oky what about php+mysql i think it make it automatic isnt it?

Comment: For mysql I don't know. Auto commit some disadvantages so hopefully it can be controlled.